# facebook manage page permission empty data

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js

I tried get a manage page permission in facbeook using javascript login api.

i passed the scope parameters

```
  FB.login(function (response) {
        FB.api("/me",
            function (response) {
                alert('Name is ' + response.name);
            });

      }
 },{
        scope: 'email,user_birthday,user_location,user_hometown,manage_pages,publish_stream'
    });

graph = require('facebook-complete'),
```

but my  page permission data is empty

i tried the following method.

```
    exports.facebookpertoken = function(currentprovidertoken, cb) {
                 var permArray = [];
        graph.extendAccessToken({
          "access_token": currentprovidertoken
           , "client_id": sails.config.global.devVm.facebook.appId
            , "client_secret": sails.config.global.devVm.facebook.app_secret

   }, function(err, facebookRes) {
       var settime = facebookRes.expires * 1000;
       var d = new Date();
       var dtime = d.setTime(settime);
         console.log(facebookRes.access_token);
      if(facebookRes.access_token){
            graph.get('me/permissions',{access_token: facebookRes.access_token} ,    function(err,permission){
             console.log({permission:JSON.stringify(permission) });

        });

  });
};
```

how can i do that above function.
any one suggest me better solution.

Thanks.

Comment: _“but my page permission data is empty”_ – what is that supposed to mean? You are aware that you don’t get a page access token by simply requesting `/me`, right?

Comment: i tried to checking the my app permission using following url graph.get('me/permissions',{access_token:''} .this url display only profile permission only granted.that why this url showing empty data. graph.get('me/accounts',{access_token: facebookRes.access_token} ,

Comment: Did you get asked for manage_pages permission during login?